# Subset dataframe using number in string?

Tags: regex, r

I have large data frame that looks something like this:

```
df1 = data.frame(A=c("A23", "A53", "B68"), B=c("Something-2030-002", "Something-4030-002",
                                               "Something-5030-002"))
```

I want to subset it to include only the observations with Something-X where X<5. That is:

```
df2 = data.frame(A=c("A23", "A53"), B=c("Something-2030-002", "Something-4030-002")
```

How can I do this with R?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub` to remove all the characters except the one digit following the first "-" and use that to create a logical index.

```
df1[sub('[^-]+-(.).*', '\\1', df1$B)<5,]
#    A                  B
#1 A23 Something-2030-002
#2 A53 Something-4030-002
```

Regex demo

```
  [^-]+-(.).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7_ejBtkoh0AeISfG)